# Fit a list in one page and keep item ratio

Tags: html, css

I have a html list which consists of multiple items, each of which is composed of some text and an image.
I want the following:

- all items must fit in one page (no scrollbar)
- each item must have the same height (resize the image to fit the item height)
- The image must use the remaining space in the item list, which is not taken by the text

Edit: so just to be clear, assuming the browser height is X, and there are n list items (li), each li should have a height of X/n pixels, so that they all fit within the browser height without any scrollbar. And from there, inside each li, the text should take whatever space it needs, and the image should fill the remaining space

I have tried playing with height & max-height but it doesn't seem to work. Should I change the html layout ?

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>

<ul>
<li>
    <div>title1</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title2</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title3</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title4</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title5</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title6</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title7</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <div>title8</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</li>
</ul>


</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: can you please give out  a mockup image of your output

Comment: First thing coming to my mind after reading your description is flexbox. Is this what you want then? https://jsfiddle.net/ejaL8u8L/

Comment: @TylerBean no it's not, sorry about being unclear in my description. What I meant is, assuming the browser height is X, and there are n list items (li), each li should have a height of X/n pixels, so that they all fit within the browser height without any scrollbar. And from there, inside each li, the text should take whatever space it needs, and the image should use the remaining space

Comment: Your description has one problem: When X/n < the minimum height of the content in one of the `li`, it's gonna overflow, even when you use javascript. It will lead to the results that there will be a scroll bar there and the heights will not be equal. In this case, you have to be sure that there are always enough space, or else it's gonna "break" out of your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't reckon this is possible with CSS only. A JS solution would be like below:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setLiHeight);
window.addEventListener("resize", setLiHeight);

function setLiHeight() {
  let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  let lis = ul.querySelectorAll("li");
  let title = ul.querySelector("div");
  let images = ul.querySelectorAll("img");

  // Set height for lis
  Array.from(lis, function(li) {
    li.style.height = ul.offsetHeight / lis.length - 1 + "px";
  });
  
  // Set height for images according to height title
  Array.from(images, function(img) {
    img.style.height = ul.offsetHeight / lis.length - title.offsetHeight + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

li img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>title1</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title2</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title3</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title4</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title5</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title6</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title7</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>title8</div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

The only assumption made here is that list's height is fixed.